# Parse all ISO 8601 DateTime formats using Java 1.8

Tags: spring-boot, datetime, java-8

I am using spring boot and Java 1.8 in my project. We are receiving a date string from an outside system which we need to parse. The problem is the outside system can send any DateTime that is ISO 8601 compliant and we need to parse any ISO 8601 format string that comes. Can anyone suggest me how to do this? is there any library for doing this?

Two DateTime formats passed are 2018-11-01T16:26:15+0100, 2018-10-31T08:27:00.0000000Z and there can be many more.

I have found some posts on StackOverflow that suggest to use Joda Time converter, but I am unable to parse the date 31T08:27:00.0000000Z with that.

Comment: The above is not parsing the format 2018-10-31T08:27:00.0000000Z

Comment: The possible formats are http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169814.htm